# Run Windows forms app from Windows service

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-services

We have a third party legacy software which we need to run from a service,  we want to automate it using window messages to click on buttons, suppress Message boxes etc.

The problem is I cant seem to start the process with the forms active, I can retrieve the process using `Process.GetProcessesByName("ProcessName");` but the `MainWindowHandle` and `MainWindowTitle` is null.

Is there a way of starting the Windows client program from the Service so that the forms are created properly?

Comment: Windows Services are running in a user context that do not have desktops. This is why you cannot use windows from services. Please try to change the user the service is using to the one you wish to open the window.

Comment: I dont want to show the Form to a real user, I want to interact with the form programmaticly, in other words I want to make a old legacy software work as a Service so that our Backend can talk to it with modern techniques like MQ or WCF

Comment: Well, I think this will not work - as I said windows services do not host an desktop by default, so you cannot create windows. :/

Comment: Ok, but how do commercial tools like AutoMate do it then? They can invoke and interact with forms without a user logged in. http://www.networkautomation.com/

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to log in a user from a service? That way I could login a User and run the program from that account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Services run in a different session from the user's desktop, the infamous session 0.  It is isolated since Vista due to a chronic problem with shatter attacks, google "session 0 isolation" to find out more about it.

Session 0 still has a desktop, you just can't switch to it.  The most typical diagnostic for getting a null MainWindowHandle is not waiting long enough to allow the process to create it.  You'll need at least Process.WaitForInputIdle().

That doesn't exactly promise a solution, you still have a very serious problem detecting that the program is misbehaving.  Or for that matter that MainWindowHandle is actually the handle of a splash screen and not the main window and is therefore null since the splash screen was dismissed.  Or that the program keeled over because it doesn't work properly with a different user account or a uncommon working directory.  Etcetera, things you need to sort out by first making this work with a console mode program before you ever try to run it as a service.

At which point is is probably best just to keep it a console mode app.  Because failure is utterly undiagnosable, this will be a constant pain in your rear end when IT staff calls you because it stopped working and you've got nothing to look at either.

Comment: this is a old Business analytics software and I do not have access to the Source code so i'm stuck with a Winforms app I'm afraid :/

Comment: Btw, i cant get any process to get a mainwindow or any window.. Are you sure that it creates handles for forms in Session 0?

Comment: I specifically warned about not being able to detect outright failure of the app.  A preview with what you'll have to deal with once you put this in production.  You really do have to make it work with a console app first.

Comment: You mean a console app instead of a Service or running a console app from a Service instead of a Forms app? I've made a SPIKE/POC and was successfully controlling the Forms app with messages from a console app. Thats working, now I just neeed to get it to work when not logged in

Comment: I actually got it to work, had to use the Win32 FindWindow instead of the C# built in version. And if I run the service in Interactive mode I can login and see the widows in action, so thats good if things does not go as expected